Security of Ring-LWE and Module-LWE encryption scheme
Regev-05 encryption under plain LWE consists in using a public key $\mathsf{pk} = (\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{A}^\top\mathbf{s}+\mathbf{e})$, where $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n\times m}$ is uniform, $\mathbf{s}\in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ is a secret vector and $\mathbf{e}\in \mathbb{Z}^m$ is an error vector, to encrypt a message $\mu \in \{0,1\}$ as follows: sample a vector $\mathbf{r}\in \{0,1\}^m$ and compute the following
$c_0 = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{r}$ and $c_1 = \mathbf{b}^\top\mathbf{r}+\mu \lfloor q/2 \rfloor$.
Security usually follows by replacing $\mathbf{b}$ by a uniform vector under LWE assumption and then using the Leftover Hash lemma to argue that $\mathbf{Ar}$ and $\mathbf{b}^\top\mathbf{r}$ is statistically closed to uniform.
Now, in the Ring-LWE and Module-LWE regime, $\mathbf{A}$, after coefficient embedding, is a structured matrix. Therefore, how those the argument of Regev-05 still apply in those settings? More precisely, given $\mathbf{A}\in R_q^{n\times m}$, where $R_q = \mathbb{Z}_q[x]/(x^{2^k}+1)$, how is $\mathbf{Ar}$ and $\mathbf{b}^\top\mathbf{r}$ random for $\mathbf{r} \in R_q^{n}$ such that each components of $\mathbf{r}$ are polynomials with binary coefficient.

The argument applies by replacing the LWE assumption with the RLWE assumption of distingushing the elements when $A$ is restricted to being of this special form.
Note that in RLWE we can think of $A$ as either being a polynomial in $\mathbb Z_q[x]/(x^{2^k}+1)$ or as a negacirculant $\mathbb Z_q^{n\times m}$ matrix, which is a means of representing the polynomial multiplication in matrix form.
Simlarly, in MLWE we can think of $A$ either as a matrix of polynomials or as a matrix of negacirculant matrices, which again would be a restriction of the LWE matrix space.

I understand that part of the hybrid argument.
But how is $\mathbf{Ar}$ and $\mathbf{b}^\top\mathbf{r}$ still random? does the leftover hash lemma still apply for those structured matrices?
Or is there an alternative proof for the plain LWE scheme that does not rely on the leftover hash lemma and that can be transported to the Ring-LWE/Module-LWE setting? i.e., proving that a random subset-sum of encryptions 0 is at least computationally indistinguishable from uniform regardless of the underlying "ring"

is the negacirculant matrix still a 2-universal hash function? from my understanding, there is definitely a dependence among entries of that matrix.

It's still 2-universal provided that the matrix is of full rank.

Daniel's answer does not appear to be correct. The leftover hash lemma is not known to hold in anywhere near the generality that it does for LWE, e.g. your concern that the situation might be different is correct.
See for example Towards a Ring analogue of the Leftover Hash Lemma.
That being said, while the situation is mildly more complex, it is still manageable. RLWE (and MLWE) based constructions need to use a certain limited form of the LHL, typically referred to as a "regularity lemma". See the above link for more details, or Section 7 of the "Toolkit for RLWE" paper for a specific "regularity lemma".
Alternatively, rather than arguing that $Ar$ and $b^t r$ are statistically close, one can use a mildly modified encryption scheme such that one shows that the analogues of these quantities are computationally close, under the LWE assumption. This is to say one obtains security under only LWE, and not LHL. This scheme then directly ports over to RLWE and MLWE. The scheme I have in mind is that of LP11, Section 3.
